# How to use Subscribers in TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typeorm

Consider the following setup with `mongodb` ( the issue is presumably database agnostic ):

entity/Person.ts

```
import { Entity, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity
export class Person {
  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

subscriber/PersonSubscriber.ts

```
import {
  EntitySubscriberInterface,
  EventSubscriber,
  InsertEvent,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Person } from '../entity/Person';

@EventSubscriber()
export class PersonSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Person> {
  listenTo() {
    return Person;
  }

  afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Person>) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

config/mongo.ts

```
import { MongoConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions';

export const mongoConfig: MongoConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mongodb',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  entities: ['src/entity/**/*.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/migration/**/*.ts'],
  subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/entity',
    migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
    subscribersDir: 'src/subscriber',
  },
};
```

index.ts

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { mongoConfig } from 'config/mongo';

createConnection(mongoConfig)
  .then(connection => {
    console.log('connection established');
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

`PersonSubscriber` is the first element of the `connection.subscribers` array, however after having inserted a Person document the `InsertEvent` is **not** logged to the console.

**What's missing?**

P.S. This is all the docs I've managed to gather

- https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md
- http://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_connection_connection_.connection.html#subscribers

All in all, they still don't tell the complete story.

Comment: How are you inserting the document?\
This question is relevant because of subscribers only fire when you insert document using **QueryBuilder** and repository/manager methods.

Answer (score 10):

the file name must be name.subscribe.ts

ormconfig

```
"subscribers": ["dist/**/**/**/*.subscriber{.ts,.js}"]
```

works for me

Answer (score -2):

Check your wildcards:

```
subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.ts']
```

probably needs to be

```
subscribers: ['src/subscriber/*.ts']
```

instead, possibly with a second entry for `*.js` files. At least this is why my subscribers did not fire - recursive globbing might be operating system dependent. Depending on your shell and OS and the way TypeORM expands asterisks internally (I dont know), running `shopt -s globstar` in the bash shell before starting the node process might also cut it.

Other than that, your paths need to match the `src/` prefix too, of course, so I assume `subscriber/PersonSubscriber.ts` in your case is actually `src/subscriber/PersonSubscriber.ts`.

Please also note that TypeORM also has a [rather unique way of parsing options](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md#which-configuration-file-is-used-by-typeorm), in case you have multiple config definitions inside environment variables, config files or createConnection() options.